# How do you approach refactoring an ugly procedure/query?

Tags: stored-procedures, query-refactor

I've inherited a database which contains several procedures which are 1000-1500 lines long, with complex nested sub-selects going up to 7 or 8 levels deep in places. I desperately need to refactor them for my own sanity, but how can I begin to do this with any level of confidence that they still work the same?

I would write unit tests if this were .Net - do you recommend a similar approach?

Comment: What database platform is this?

Comment: @Leigh: I was going for more general advice, but it happens to be SQL Server 2005.

Comment: How do you mean "support for them"? You can write unit tests in any language. Here is [a tool](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/) for T-SQL for example.

Comment: @Gaius: Thanks, I wasn't aware of tools for unit testing T-SQL - this is part of the reason I asked the question. I edited it to take out that wording.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes, create unit tests.**  This is really the only way to ensure that a modified version meets the same requirements as the original.

To refactor the procedures look for any repeating patterns of code that could be extracted into separate procedures or nested procedures.  If the procedures are still too long break parts of it into separate procedures that each complete one task.  As you break off new procedures you should add unit tests for it.

Seven or eight levels of sub-selects does sound excessive, but you may find that some or even most of these are necessary to produce the data required.  I would focus on the procedure initially and then tackle the SQL.

To do unit testing in Oracle, the foremost commercial product for testing is [Quest's Code Tester](http://www.quest.com/code-tester-for-oracle/).  Oracle has Unit Testing built into it's free [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) product.  The question [Unit testing for PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152441/unit-testing-for-pl-sql) on StackOverflow has some other options or you can just write your own tests.

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone know of similar tools for SQL Server?

Comment: A brief search seems to indicate that the state of procedure testing is as bad for Microsoft as it is for Oracle.  Here is the StackOverflow answer to this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765212/how-do-you-unit-test-your-t-sql

Answer (score 4):

maybe you could find good advice in here:

- [How to dive into an ugly database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/929/how-to-dive-into-an-ugly-database)

In the meantime, try to identify nasty-looking queries, like the ones that use `where` instead of `joins`.

Answer (score 2):

As for my two cents here, I generally run it through a reformatter if I can, to get things to a traceable level, because anything that's 1500 lines unless already reformattered is going to be a little rough to trace by hand.

Then I try and put deeply nested selects into temp tables to reduce the nesting.

Then I try and figure out if it can be split into contiguous chunks of code, that can be extracted to run by themselves (think like making smaller functions out of a single long method of C#) and encapsulated to prevent too much information being presented in one long stretch.

Those are my basics that I toss at the problem before getting too far off topic